# Borrar item de la lista la IP que comience con "198.1"

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo una lista con IP Address y necesito eliminar las IPs que no corresponden a mi red que son las "198.1".

```
class HostInfo
{
    public List<IPAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando se agregan las IPs se hacen algunas de una columna y otras de dos, necesito poder filtrar o eliminar las IPs que empiezan con "198.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tomando algo de ayuda de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503756/converting-ipaddress-to-string) una solución podría ser:

cambiar tu property para que sea algo así:

```
   const string myNetwork = "198.1";

   private List<IPAddresses> _addresses;
   public List<IPAddress> Addresses 
   { 
       get { return _addresses }
       set {
            _addresses = value.Where(c => c.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork &&
                                          c.ToString().StartsWith(myNetwork)).ToList();
        }
   }
```

adonde no estarías realmente borrando los que no están sino filtrando los que si, y volviéndolos a asignar a la lista original, pero el resultado es el esperado, o no?

habría que agregar el siguiente using si aún no lo tuvieras...

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Cambie la preguna, puedes ayudarme con esta? No encuentro logica para aplicar tu codigo en una lista donde no hay "ip" y "ip2" como nombres.

Comment: ok, ```IPAddress``` es una clase tuya o es de framework? habría que ver como filtrar ahi, pero básicamente al ser una property yo filtraría al hacer el get y almacenaría solo las filtradas en la property

Comment: Es del framework

Comment: te sirvió finalmente?

Comment: Claro, con el codigo que usted publico lo solucione, exactamente eso era. Gracias, Eugenio